# Stunman dropping into a car

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics

I need to make a plan for a stunt man that is hanging off of a cliff at 5 m high. He must land into a car that will be passing underneath (using a constant acceleration). I am stuck on which equation to use that would represent the man dropping into the car

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the $s=u_yt+\frac{1}{2} g t^2$ kinematics formula. Let's assume your stuntman just drops from that height . Thus making your time of descent $t=\sqrt{\frac{10}{g}} sec$

Now plan your stunt accordingly .

The horizontal displacement of the car must be planned accordingly so that it reaches the location of drop exactly at $t$ sec (Preferably , a bit before that)

Comment: How will the cars constant acceleration play into this?

Comment: $x=\frac{1}{2}a t^2$ assuming the car was initially at rest and $a$ is acceleration of car @JenniferKuhnPometo

Comment: @JenniferKuhnPometo You may acept the answer if it was helpful to you